# html.status_code возвращает пустое значение

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://auto.ru/balashiha/cars/skoda/all/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1'} , {'accept' : '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    print(html.status_code)
```

Comment: `None`?8 символов нужно...

Comment: запускаю в консоле, просто пустая строка

Comment: `''`?10 символов нужно...

Comment: просто ничего не возвращает

Comment: Функция в питоне всегда чего-нибудь возвращает...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: А чего вы хотели: функции надо вызывать ;)

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':parse()`    ??